# Creating a new item or editing existing one makes column jump

Tags: reactjs

I have created a small grid using a React library that allows a user to create new items, edit them and remove them. It also has sorting functionality. The grid works and it gets sorted, you can remove, edit, etc but for some reason when I add a new item or edit an existing one the column jumps to a different position and I am not sure why this behavior occurs. I want to be able to create new entries and edit existing ones without having the entire column jump somewhere else. How can I prevent this behavior? Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid, GridColumn, GridCell, GridToolbar } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { DropDownList } from '@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns';
import { sampleProducts } from './sample-products.jsx';

import { orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';

class DropDownCell extends React.Component {
  localizedData = [
    { text: 'yes', value: true },
    { text: 'no', value: false },
    { text: '(empty)', value: null }
  ];

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange({
      dataItem: this.props.dataItem,
      field: this.props.field,
      syntheticEvent: e.syntheticEvent,
      value: e.target.value.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const dataValue = this.props.dataItem[this.props.field];

    if (!this.props.dataItem.inEdit) {
      return (
        <td>
          {(dataValue === null) ? '' : this.props.dataItem[this.props.field].toString()}
        </td>
      );
    }

    return (
      <td>
        <DropDownList
          style={{ width: "100px" }}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.localizedData.find(c => c.value === dataValue)}
          data={this.localizedData}
          textField="text"
        />
      </td>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: sampleProducts.slice(0),
      // Specify the state variable responsible for the edit state of the component.
      inEdit: false,
      sort: [
        { field: 'ProductName', dir: 'asc' }
      ]
    };

    this.enterInsert = this.enterInsert.bind(this);
    this.itemChange = this.itemChange.bind(this);

    const enterEdit = this.enterEdit.bind(this);
    const save = this.save.bind(this);
    const cancel = this.cancel.bind(this);
    const remove = this.remove.bind(this);

    class MyCommandCell extends GridCell {
      render() {
        return !this.props.dataItem.inEdit ?
          (
            <td>
              <button
                className="k-primary k-button k-grid-edit-command"
                onClick={() => enterEdit(this.props.dataItem)}
              > Edit
                                </button>
              <button
                className="k-button k-grid-remove-command"
                onClick={() => confirm('Confirm deleting: ' + this.props.dataItem.ProductName) &&
                  remove(this.props.dataItem)}
              > Remove
                                </button>
            </td>
          ) : (
            <td>
              <button
                className="k-button k-grid-save-command"
                onClick={() => save(this.props.dataItem)}
              > {this.props.dataItem.ProductID ? 'Update' : 'Add'}
              </button>
              <button
                className="k-button k-grid-cancel-command"
                onClick={() => cancel(this.props.dataItem)}
              >{this.props.dataItem.ProductID ? 'Cancel' : 'Discard'}
              </button>
            </td>
          );
      }
    }

    this.CommandCell = MyCommandCell;
  }

  enterInsert() {
    const dataItem = { inEdit: true, Discontinued: false };
    const newproducts = this.state.data.slice();
    newproducts.unshift(dataItem);
    this.update(newproducts, dataItem);
    this.setState({
      data: newproducts
    });
  }

  enterEdit(dataItem) {
    this.update(this.state.data, dataItem).inEdit = true;
    // Set the current edit state
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.slice(),
      inEdit: true
    });
  }

  save(dataItem) {
    dataItem.inEdit = undefined;
    dataItem.ProductID = this.update(sampleProducts, dataItem).ProductID;
    // Set the current edit state
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.slice(),
      inEdit: false
    });
  }

  cancel(dataItem) {
    if (dataItem.ProductID) {
      let originalItem = sampleProducts.find(p => p.ProductID === dataItem.ProductID);
      this.update(this.state.data, originalItem);
    } else {
      this.update(this.state.data, dataItem, !dataItem.ProductID);
    }
    // Set the current edit state
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.slice(),
      inEdit: false
    });
  }

  remove(dataItem) {
    dataItem.inEdit = undefined;
    this.update(this.state.data, dataItem, true);
    this.update(sampleProducts, dataItem, true);
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.slice()
    });
  }

  itemChange(event) {
    const value = event.value;
    const name = event.field;
    if (!name) {
      return;
    }
    const updatedData = this.state.data.slice();
    const item = this.update(updatedData, event.dataItem);
    item[name] = value;
    this.setState({
      data: updatedData
    });
  }

  update(data, item, remove) {
    let updated;
    let index = data.findIndex(p => p === item || item.ProductID && p.ProductID === item.ProductID);
    if (index >= 0) {
      updated = Object.assign({}, item);
      data[index] = updated;
    } else {
      let id = 1;
      data.forEach(p => { id = Math.max(p.ProductID + 1, id); });
      updated = Object.assign({}, item, { ProductID: id });
      data.unshift(updated);
      index = 0;
    }

    if (remove) {
      return data.splice(index, 1)[0];
    }

    return data[index];
  }

  handleSortChange = (e) => {
    // Prevent Sort change if any row is in edit mode!
    if(this.state.inEdit) {return;}
    this.setState({
      sort: e.sort
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid
          data={orderBy(this.state.data, this.state.sort)}
          onItemChange={this.itemChange}
          sortable={true}
          sort={this.state.sort}
          editField="inEdit"
          onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
        >
          <GridToolbar>
            <button
              title="Add new"
              className="k-button k-primary"
              onClick={this.enterInsert}
            >Add new
                        </button>

            {this.state.data.filter(p => p.inEdit).length > 0 && (
              <button
                title="Cancel current changes"
                className="k-button"
                onClick={() => this.setState({ data: sampleProducts.slice() })}
              >Cancel current changes
                            </button>
            )}
          </GridToolbar>
          <GridColumn field="ProductID" title="Id" width="50px" editable={false} />
          <GridColumn field="ProductName" title="Product Name" />
          <GridColumn field="FirstOrderedOn" title="First Ordered" editor="date" format="{0:d}" />
          <GridColumn field="UnitsInStock" title="Units" editor="numeric" />
          <GridColumn field="Discontinued" cell={DropDownCell} />
          <GridColumn cell={this.CommandCell} />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('my-app')
);
```

Here is a runnable example showing the behavior:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dsufbx-k3jvcl?file=app/main.jsx

Comment: The reason for the jumping column is the table gets sorted every time you write something in a new row input.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting your data on every item change. The better way would be to sort it while you click only on UPDATE button. Try below code.

```
save(dataItem) {
    dataItem.inEdit = undefined;
    dataItem.ProductID = this.update(sampleProducts, dataItem).ProductID;
    // Set the current edit state
    this.setState({
      data: orderBy(this.state.data.slice(), this.state.sort),
      inEdit: false
    });
}
.
.
.
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid
          data={this.state.data}
          onItemChange={this.itemChange}
          sortable={true}
          sort={this.state.sort}
          editField="inEdit"
          onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
        >
```